# How to determine if the current Windows session is locked or not?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi

I have an application which runs every hour on a Windows XP Machine. To run properly, this application requires the current session to be unlocked. So I was wondering if there a way to know if the current Windows session is locked or not with C# and .NET 3.5.

UPDATE: The application cannot listen to the SessionNotification events. The application can be kicked off anytime and terminates when completed.

Thanks!

Comment: What does it do that it can't run when the session is locked?

Answer (score 1):

These are untested by me, but look interesting. I'd give them a test, but my Visual Studio appears to be less than happy with me at the moment.

- <s>[Is there any way a program can know whether or not the computer is locked?](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://www.eggheadcafe.com/forumarchives/platformsdksecurity/Jan2006/post24990381.asp) (google cache link, thanks @hometoast)</s> (link permanently dead)
- [Lots of information in this thread](http://www.devnewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework/topic52723.aspx)
- If your app can run all the time and "wake up" once an hour, the [SystemEvents.SessionSwitch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionswitch(VS.80).aspx) event might help you out, there's an example in the thread above

Comment: The eggheadcafe link is 404'd

Comment: The cache link is 404'd

Answer (score 0):

I once used the [`GetForegroundWindow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633505(VS.85).aspx) function to determine whether a screen saver was running. If the return value was `NULL`, then the screen saver (or, presumably, a locked workstation) was active. Note that this was in the early days of Windows NT, is not documented to do this, and there's no guarantee that it will still do the same thing today.

Looking at the Win32 API reference, you may be able to use something like [`OpenInputDesktop()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684309(VS.85).aspx) to get the `HDESK` of the currently active desktop. If you can't get a handle to the desktop or if it's different from your thread desktop, then your app is running in a desktop that is not active (and the workstation is probably either in a screensaver state or is locked). No guarantees that this method will work, but it might be worth investigating.